# Device_state function return the status inuse instead of onhold in AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am getting SIP/Peer status using getvar action in AMI. It return INUSE status once the call answered and it also return INUSE when the call in hold. How to get the ONHOLD status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sip.conf, change the value of notifyhold to yes, its default value is no. Now you can get the ONHOLD status.